# how make glowing effect for a real time ajax div block

Tags: javascript, ajax, real-time, effects

i have an Ajax code to catch results from a txt file in real time, then results automatically showing in a div block with below lines:

```
if (xmlhttp.responseText != "") {
    InnerHTMLText = xmlhttp.responseText + document.getElementById("div").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = InnerHTMLText;
}
```

as you can see. this code first get already results from div block and add it with xmlhttp.responseText, then show all, in div block again.

my problem is to **show new results with a glowing or fading effect**.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at my code if its helpful to you.
i have just used css3 for glow border of div

```
http://jsfiddle.net/yncqk/16/
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".glow")
        .bind("fadeglow", function() {        
            $(this)
                .fadeOut(1000)
                .fadeIn(1000)
                .trigger("fadeglow");
        }).trigger("fadeglow");
   }
);
​
```